# Mimic sessions in database: How to determine obsolete values?

Tags: session, cookies, login-control

I had a session system, where logged users where stored in session (in memory). The problem of this is that the application can't scale out (clone server). It can only scale up (improve server).

Now: my new user system consists on a users table and a cookies table, both in the database.

```
 Users(username, hashedpassword)
 Cookies(username, secretcookie, expiration)
```

The login form includes three fields: "username", "password" and a checkbox for "stay connected".

The code that handles the form, in pseudo code, is the following:

```
 if username and password are correct 
 {
      secretValue = new GUID();
      create a cookie in the client, containing the secretValue.

      if (stayConnected)
      {
           -make the cookie expire in 30 days
           -add to table "Cookies" this registry: (username, secretValue, now+30days)
      }
      else
      {
           -dont set an expiration date (ie: cookie expires when browser closes)
           -add to table "Cookies" this registry: (username, secretValue, null)
      }
 }
```

This is almost the same as using sessions, but I'm now using the database instead of memory.
I know its vulnerable to session hijaking but my previous system was too.

The question is:
**My "Cookies" table contains a lot of obsolete values (cookies that already expired in the client because he closed the browser), whats a good policy to determine which ones to delete?**

Comment: you need to setup a script on the backend that will every once in awhile that will delete any cookies that have an expiration date less than now

Comment: those are easy to delete, but what about the cookies that dont have an expiration date? the ones that are supposed to expire when the browser closes (ie: no explicit date). How do I manage those?